# can't spread the data directly from mysql?

Tags: mysql, r, dplyr, tidyr

I have a dataset more than 2G, and would like to make some adjustment without touching the MySQL efficiency or RAM-limitation issues.

```
>con <- src_mysql(dbname="data")
>dt <- con %>% tbl<"data">
# Source:   query [?? x 11]
# Database: mysql 5.7.17-log [root@localhost:/data]
# 
# No          ID    DATA    UNIT               RECORD
# <int>    <chr>    <chr>  <chr>                 <chr>
# 1      1 U1234        12   Xtm  2014-11-02T17:58:17Z
# 2      2 U1234     3.461   RSD  2014-11-02T17:58:17Z
# 3      3 U1234         9   Xtm  2014-11-02T17:58:17Z
# 4      4 U1234     0.329   RSD  2014-11-02T17:58:17Z
# 5      5 U1234        55   Xtm  2014-11-02T17:58:17Z
# 6      6 U1234     1.174   RSD  2014-11-02T17:58:17Z
# 7      7 U1234        63   Xtm  2014-11-02T17:58:17Z
# 8      8 U1234     6.110   RSD  2014-11-02T17:58:17Z
# 9      9 U1234        33   Xtm  2014-11-02T17:58:17Z
# 10    10 U1234     3.072   RSD  2014-11-02T17:58:17Z
# ... with more rows
```

Try to spread the data in to 2 colums based on UNIT(Xtm, RSD), but always get the error msg,

`Error: Key column 'UNIT' does not exist in input.`

my question is how to  spread the table **without** loading whole dataset from MySQL? Say,

```
dt2 <- con %>% tbl("data") %>% spread(UNIT,DATA)    ## which is not correct.
```

I was hoping a new dataset as:

```
# No          ID    Xtm   RSD                RECORD
# <int>    <chr>    <chr><chr>                <chr>
# 1      1 U1234     12   3.41 2014-11-02T17:58:17Z
```

`i wonder if the err msg is about the col name 'UNIT' is reserved, but even I rename it, the error msg still pops up. Tried to search everywhere for days, and very little information could be found.

Please help.

PS. Earlier I asked the question, but wrongly marked answered. The answer is good, yet didn't touch the core issue about the MySQL-spread combibnation.

Comment: have tried, `spread(tbl_df(dt), key = UNIT, value = DATA)`, it also collects all data from MySQL and took so long to genreate the results. I was using **data.table**. It still works when all data is retrived.

Comment: I don't know of any efficient way to spread in database.

Comment: thank you very much, @hadley not only for the advice, but also for your great work!